# I have a problem with the donnut beginner tutorial

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, proportional-editing

Im new in blender (and every other modeling program). I started to understand blender and how to use it but when I make the donut (followinf Guru's tutorial), I get some problems like the icing not getting stick with the donut, or having an hexagon in one part of the donut, or some clipping through the icing, and three triangles that I cant correct.
If someone can help me on knowing how to fix this and where did I went wrong, I would appreciate it.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. Rather than take photos of your monitor post actual screenshots instead, see [How to take a screenshot](https://www.take-a-screenshot.org). Photos are harder to read because we have to look past external interferences (like reflections, smudges or Moiré patterns) and guess if we are looking at hardware issues such as a malfunctioning display or connections, a software level issue like driver malfunction or glitch, or actual artifacts or issues with the model itself.

Comment: Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue in such way that anyone searching for a similar problem may easily find it. Use the [edit] link above, remove anything superfluous, avoid words like "*this*","*issue with*" or "*question about*". Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, answers you get depend heavily on how inviting it is. See ["*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: Hello could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Type 'donut icing' (without the quotes) into the search box at the top of this page and you'll find many, many questions and answers about problems with the donut icing in that tutorial, quite a few addressing the issue that you seem to be having.